# Bot Framework Email channel slow response time

Tags: email, botframework, azure-qna-maker, response-time

I created basic QnA Maker and connected it to Web App Bot service in Azure. I configured the Email channel with o365 account. When I send a message to that email  it takes 5-10 minutes until I get the response back. It seems as if the bot was checking the inbox every 10 minutes or something. But since this is probably a setting of the email channel, I cannot change it in a code.

I would really appreciate any help provided. Thanks

Comment: Does it take that long only the first time you send a message or its the case for every response?

Comment: Every response takes so long :/ i have tried already about 30 messages and still no immediate response

Comment: Could you paste your Bot Handle? Also, can you add Application Insights to both the bot and the web application hosting the bot?

Comment: @ranusharao what do you mean by Bot handle? I think any of this is irrelevant. I just created the bot the way it should be created and it is obvious that the implementation of email channel is that it is checking inbox every 10 minutes. I dont think its my specific problem :/

Comment: The email channel is not implemented to check your inbox every 10 minutes.  A bot handle represents a bot's registration with the online Azure Bot Service(basically the bot name with which you used while registering). I would need either your bot name or App ID to look up the email channel logs for the bot. Also, it would be helpful if you post your bot code.

Comment: @ranusharao okay so the bot handle is generaliqnabot. Bot code was not changed, it is the same as it is when its generated. Thanks :)

Comment: Our logs show your bot is timing out and attempting to resend the email continuously. At some point of time in between 5-10 minutes, it succeeds and you get the response. This timeout is the cause of your delay. If you configure application insights, then you can figure out what is causing the delay. [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#other-considerations) will help you configure your email and [this](https://github.com/daveta/analytics/blob/master/troubleshooting_timeout.md) will help you solve timeouts.

Comment: further looking at your email logs, it seems there might be an issue with your email configuration. Can you delete and reconfigure the channel?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I didnt have much time yet but i will post update when I do progress.

Comment: @ranusharao I tried to set the alway on property on QnAMaker service and also on BotWebApp service but didnt help. I configured the application insights but i can see that as soon as it gets to my bot handle it gets executed correctly. I also tried removing the email channel and configure it once again but didnt work. 

What I observed is:
When I send an email at for example 11:25, I get the response 11:32. When I send it 11:49, the response comes 11:52. What I am trying to say is, that it is more than obvious that the mailbox gets checked every 10 minutes and then it handles the email.